# Sending email using VB code only works locally not from webserver

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, smtp

I am using the code below to generate an email and it works fine locally in development but when I try it over the web it does not work? Do I need to do something different or can this not be accomplished over the web using it this way?

```
 Try


    Dim mailMessage As MailMessage = New MailMessage
    mailMessage.From = New MailAddress("Test@whatever.com")
    'mailMessage.Subject = txtSubject.Text.Trim
    'mailMessage.Body = txtBody.Text.Trim
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
        mailMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress("Test@whatever.com"))
    ' Dim files As List(Of HttpPostedFile) = CType(Session("Files"), List(Of HttpPostedFile))
    'For Each file As HttpPostedFile In files
    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(New Attachment("\\Server\test.pdf"))
    'Next

    Dim smtp As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient

    smtp.Host = "Mail.com"

        'smtp.EnableSsl = True

    Dim NetworkCred As System.Net.NetworkCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    smtp.Send(mailMessage)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: What error messages are you receiving, if any? Also, check your anti-virus. A big issue that a lot of people run into is their anti-virus blocking outbound mail.

Comment: I am not receiving an error messages or anything in eventviewer. Also there is no antivirus installed on the webserver

Comment: But, in your example code, you are catching and ignoring all exceptions, so if it was throwing an exception, you wouldn't see it anyway.

Comment: Would I put a message box to show me the error?

Comment: Either put in the message box or remove the try/catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using network credentials, such as those that the SMTP server may require?

```
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

Comment: I tried adding that line u suggested and still no email was sent

Comment: is smtp.UseDefaultCredentials set to false or still true? ... Please set it to false ... get maybe any exception?